# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, one-to-many

So I've been wrestling with this for a couple of days now, googled and googled and moved things around to no avail :/.

Here's the scenario: A Company can have many products.

When I try to create a new company and a catalog for it, it creates the catalog but doesn't add the product and it adds the company to the company table.

On top of that I get this error:

> Cannot add or update a child row: 
>   a foreign key constraint fails (`Swifft`.`Master_Catalog_Testiandoq2`, CONSTRAINT `Master_Catalog_Testiandoq2_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Company_ID`) REFERENCES `Companies` (`Company_ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Here's what I Have:

```
<?php  include'../Maestro.php';
    //pull all the values from the form.
    $CompName  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['CompName']);
    $CompName  = ucwords($CompName); //capitalize the first letter of every word

    $ProdSKU   = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ProdSku']);
    $ProdName  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ProdName']);
    $ProdPrice = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ProdPrice']);
    $ProdDesc  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ProdDesc']);
    $ProdStat  = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['ProdStat']);

    echo $CompName . '. . ';
    $CompName  = str_replace(' ', '_', $CompName); // replace spaces with underscores
```

So this piece right here, it creates the table with no problem.
But I think I got the foreign Key wrong.

```
    //create a new Master Catalog table for the new company if it doesn't already exist.
    $sql2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Master_Catalog_{$CompName} (
    _ID INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    Company_ID INT(11) NOT NULL,
    Product_Sku VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    Product_Name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Product_Price DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL,
    Product_Description MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
    Product_Status TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    Product_DateAdded DATE NOT NULL,
    Product_DateRemoved DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY(_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Company_ID) REFERENCES Companies(Company_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)";
```

and then the products don't get added to the catalog for some reason.

```
    //add products to the Master Catalog table
    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO Master_Catalog_{$CompName} (
    Product_Sku,
    Product_Name,
    Product_Price,
    Product_Description,
    Product_Status,
    Product_DateAdded)

    VALUES (
    '$ProdSKU',
    '$ProdName',
    '$ProdPrice',
    '$ProdDesc',
    '$ProdStat',
    CURDATE()
    )";

    //check if company exists
    $checkTable = "SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE Company_Name = '{$CompName}' ";
    $result = $conn->query($checkTable);

    //if company does not exists the add it.
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
            echo "there is no row named ". $CompName . ", Im gonna add it.<br/>";
            $sql  = "INSERT INTO Companies (Company_Name, Date_Added) VALUES ('{$CompName}', CURDATE() )";
            $conn -> query($sql) . mysqli_error($conn);
            echo "Complete!";
    }else {
            echo "there is a row named " . $CompName;
    }

    if($conn -> query($sql2) == TRUE){
            echo' Master catalog table created.';
    }else {
            echo " table exists. ";
            echo 'it na work :/'. mysqli_error($conn);}

    if($conn -> query($sql3) == TRUE){
            echo' products added to Master catalog';
    }else {echo 'something exploded! :O'. mysqli_error($conn);}

?>
```

Comment: Why are you creating a separate table for each company, the Company_ID column on the table already takes care of that for you. It will make querying these tables a complete nightmare.

Comment: I'm not, I'm making a separate table for the acatalog of each company because they're all going to have different products

Comment: That's fine, you can filter it by the Company_ID when you query it. `SELECT * FROM Master_Catalog WHERE Company_ID = ?;`

Comment: Augwa's advice still applies, there is no need for multiple tables unless different companies' products have drastically different properties.

Comment: To add to @Uueerdo point, in that case you'd simply add a vertical table to manage the additional attributes.

Comment: I thought about doing it like that at first but then it's gonna be a huge table when I have 30+ companies with 1000's of products in there. I figured it would be quicker to look them up by company specifically.

Comment: @GeneralCan no .... that's the whole point of the database, you keep like data together, not fragmented like you've done. You then index your tables accordingly and then if your database gets really big (which at this point I doubt you have to worry about that), then you look at sharding and partitioning

Comment: To add to @GeneralCan most recent point... if/when the data does grow large enough for concern, you can PARTITION the table based on company_id; which indicate to the database to separate products into separate data files by company_id so that the entire dataset will always not need "opened".

Comment: alright, That makes sense. But how do I get the foreing Key to work? because I would still need it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the order you do things because before you can insert into the Master_Catalog_{$CompName} table, the company must exist in the Companies table due to your foreign key constraint. As well you don't allow nulls on the Company_ID which means you also need to include it in the insert statement.

```
//check if company exists
$checkTable = "SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE Company_Name = '{$CompName}' ";
$result = $conn->query($checkTable);

//if company does not exists the add it.
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
        echo "there is no row named ". $CompName . ", Im gonna add it.<br/>";
        $sql  = "INSERT INTO Companies (Company_Name, Date_Added) VALUES ('{$CompName}', CURDATE() )";
        $conn -> query($sql) . mysqli_error($conn);
        echo "Complete!";
        $CompanyId = $conn->last_insert_id;
}else {
        echo "there is a row named " . $CompName;
}

//add products to the Master Catalog table
$sql3 = "INSERT INTO Master_Catalog_{$CompName} (
Company_ID,
Product_Sku,
Product_Name,
Product_Price,
Product_Description,
Product_Status,
Product_DateAdded)

VALUES (
$CompanyId,
'$ProdSKU',
'$ProdName',
'$ProdPrice',
'$ProdDesc',
'$ProdStat',
CURDATE()
)";
```

Comment: that's how I have it. It first inserts into acompanies a new company then it creates the master catalog table and then it adds the product to the master catalog table. thats the order I placed the if statements in

Comment: shoud I remove the NOT NULL from Company_ID?

Comment: oops right you are, well needless to say the Company_ID column needs to be filled in. As I mentioned above you should actually make use of this Company_ID column as shown above and stop creating separate tables for each company.

Comment: so If I allow Company_ID to be NULL it adds the product to the table without errors, but says NULL for the Company_ID field. how do I make it have the same ID as in the company table?

Comment: look at my answer its in there

Comment: ahh I see. I thought Foreing Keys automatically added the value of the key it is referencing (or something lol). I have to add the value using a var?